# "App can’t be opened using the Built-in Administrator account. Sign in with a different account and try again" - even with UAC enabled

Tags: windows-10

This is a bit of a strange one really. On a small subset of our computers (all running Windows 10 Pro 1607 64-bit) - with nothing obviously in common, other than that they were not clean installations of Windows 10, we get the famous "X can’t be opened using the Built-in Administrator account.  Sign in with a different account and try again" error.

This is despite:

- A: UAC GPOs being seemingly configured in the way that they're supposed to be (*User Account Control Admin Approval Mode for the Built-in Administrator account* enabled)
- B: All users in question being Domain Users, and I'm not sure they're all admins on their computers (although I know one at least is)
- C: Many other PCs having 0 issue with the exact same GPOs active (regardless of the user being an admin or not - or even a Domain Admin!)

Any ideas?

Comment: If **"All users in question being Domain Users"** It doesn't matter whether **"...they're all admins on their computers"**, because a domain user, being a member of local administrators group or not, is not a built-in Administrator anyway. A built-in Administrator, is a predefined and irremovable account, not a group, so you can't add any domain (nor local users) to delegate it's privileges. BTW, the SID of built-in Administrator account always ends in 500 (e.g. S-1-5-21-XXXXXXXX-YYYYYYYYYY-ZZZZZZZZZZ-500).

Comment: I know a domain user isn't a built-in admin account, that's why it's a problem. The point was that not everyone who is affected has ANY kind of admin rights, much less is a built-in admin.